# html in page navigation with tab button rtl

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, right-to-left

I have an HTML form with bootstrap css, when I press the Tab button on my keyboard, the fields are selected starting from the left of the screen to the right of it (as it usualy happens in ltr sites).
I want the fields to be selected from right to left of the page.
all my website is already assigned to rtl (using dir="rtl" attribute at the html tag)

I have canceled all the dir="ltr" elements

I would like to know what is the right css attribute that turns the in page navigation from right to left as it happens in this site http://business.jeeran.com/.

TNX

Comment: I am using this bootstrap template http://www.gettemplate.com/demo/progressus/index.html.  if i do float: right at the css dosn't turn the fields mark order.

Comment: I've edited my answer for you to apply to that exact theme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case of the site you've shown, it's a case of building the site in the order that you tab through the page, combined with a `float: right;`. The `float: right;` causes the items to be shown from right to left, making the most right item the first item being loaded in the HTML.

If you're able to change the layout of your site in such a way, you can do this the same way.

An example of this is:

```
<ul class="navigation">
    <li><a href="#">First item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Second item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Etc.</a></li>
</ul>
```

By adding the following CSS, the first item will be positioned most right, with the next items showing up to the left of it.

```
.navigation li {
    float: right;
}
```

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3mugeLLb/) for an example.

---

An other option is to use `tabindex`. `Tabindex` set's the tab order of the items. However, this is more of a manual way to do this than the above mentioned method.

An example of this method:

```
<ul class="navigation">
    <li><a href="#" tabindex="3">Last item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" tabindex="2">Second item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" tabindex="1">First item</a></li>
</ul>
```

And a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yfLpx8ew/) to show how it works

---

---

### Edit

When looking at the theme in your comment, that would mean changing the following CSS

```
.navbar-nav>li {
    float: left;
}
```

to float right:

```
.navbar-nav>li {
    float: right;
}
```

This would cause the main menu to be inverted as in the first example. Let me know if this solves your problems.

That same could be done to the contact us form by changing the `float: left;` on `.col-sm-4` to `float: right;`

Answer (score 1):

[TabIndex](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_tabindex.asp) is the property you need.
Objects with DESCENDING TabIndex will be selected from right to left.

Example

```
<div tabindex="3"></div><div tabindex="2"></div><div tabindex="1"></div>
```

Using Tab you will select the divs from right to left.

Comment: o.k is it possible without using tabindex?  bootstrap rtl defult nab is rtl wihout using tabindex